# Do we have a verb to express that we talk and share very personal information with someone?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

We often share our secrets or very private personal information with someone that we trust, like our best friends or people that we know very well.

Do we have a verb to say that we talk with someone, telling them all our secrets or deep private personal information?

For example, *I **chat** with my best friend*, or *I **confide in** my best friend*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Confide" works well only if you are speaking particularly of private information that one wouldn't tell nearly anyone.  We nearly always "confide (something) in" our best friends, not "confide to":  "I know that I can confide in you".

I think I nearly always resort to descriptions for this; I might write "We had a deep, personal conversation" or "I wish I had someone that I could really talk to about things dear to me.

One common adjective is **"heart-to-heart"**, for example: "I tried to have a heart-to-heart conversation with my wife, but she was too tired to take me seriously."  This usually connotes that there is a certain topic that needs to be discussed, unless it is used with more generalizing context clues, such as "I really like talking with Ann; our chats are always so heart-to-heart."